# How to rename the oldest file (acc to CreationDate) among a bunch of files having the same name

Tags: c#, linq

A folder contains 3 files as shown below:

```
FileName               CreationDate
file_1.docx            3/7/2016  1:00pm
file_1.pdf             3/7/2016  4:00pm
file_1.txt             3/7/2016  6:00pm
```

My requirement is that the oldest file(in this case, file_1.docx) should be renamed to file.docx

The other two files (file_1.pdf and file_1.txt) should remain as it is.

Please advise something in C# and LINQ.

Comment: So, check your extension and if it is `docx`, change your file name? What have  you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: Not necessarily docx...the oldest file could be anything (docx or pdf or txt). I have written a linq query which sorts the files based on their creation timestamp (i.e. oldest file would be moved to top). Not sure what to do after this step.

Comment: get files, sort by last updated date, take oldest one.. its really easy if you try

Comment: @SonerGönül I think the OP means they could be in any order not always *.docx being the oldest, something like my answer?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Maybe. It is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the following code to get all of the files and create a [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object out of them. From this object you can get the `CreationDate`, something like the following:

```
string strFileToRename = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "file_1.*")
                         .OrderBy(f => new FileInfo(f).CreationTime)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

The code finds all of the files in the directory supplied by `directoryPath` which have a name like `file_1.` and any extension. It then orders them by their `CreationDate` given by the `FileInfo` object. Lastly it selects the first one from this list, however if the list is empty it will return null. Lastly I haven't tested this so you might need to use `OrderByDescending` instead of just `OrderBy` to get the required return result.

**EDIT:**
For the sake of completion, here is how I would rename the file:

```
string strNewName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectory(strFileToRename), "File" + Path.GetExtension(strFileToRename));
File.Move(strFileToRename, strNewName);
```

The code above gets the original directory of the file, which you should know anyway from `directoryPath`. It then renames the original file name from `File_1` to `File` including the extension gotten from the original file. I then move the file which renames it.

Note: To do this safely I would use `File.Copy` then `File.Delete` when it has safely copied the file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
    File oldestFile = YourList.OrderBy(l =>l.CreationDate)
                              .FirstOrDefault();// getting oldest file

    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(string oldestFile.FileName);//take extension

    string Rename = "new name " + extension;//concanate new name and extension

    YourList.OrderBy(l =>l.CreationDate)
           .Select(l =>  l.FileName)
           .FirstOrDefault().FileName = Rename; // update new name
```

**NOTE:** I didn't test this code. I hope this helps to you

Comment: Why manually get the extension when there is `System.IO.Path.GetExtension(string path)`?

Comment: Also `oldestFile` is of type `File` but you are selecting a `string` and you then assign the name to the `File` object but never actually move/rename the actual file i.e. `File.Move(oldPath, newPath);`

Answer (score 0):

Get all "file_1" files from your directory, order them by `CreationTime` and select the first one - being your oldest file. Then `Move` your oldest file with your new name:

```
FileInfo f = Directory.GetFiles(directory_path, "file_1.*")
                      .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
                      .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
                      .FirstOrDefault();

if (f != null) File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.Replace("file_1", "file"));
```

Comment: By the time I posted you didn't provide what the user wanted, how to rename the file. Plus it is not the same getter as I return a `FileInfo` and not a `string` - I find it better and shorter to move the file. Note that there is not many ways to get the oldest file though, hence the similarities...